# gcc linking with static libraries

Tags: c, gcc

I am reading a book titled "An Introduction to GCC" and would like some clarification. The **book indicates that the code below will cause an error** but when I compile, it **builds and runs** perfectly:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
  double x = sqrt (2.0);
  printf ("The square root of 2.0 is %f\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

I quote from the book "*Trying to create an executable from this source file alone causes the compiler to give an error at the link stage:*"

```
$ gcc -Wall calc.c -o calc
/tmp/ccbR6Ojm.o: In function `main':
/tmp/ccbR6Ojm.o(.text+0x19): undefined reference 
  to `sqrt'
```

The solution that the book gives is that you are supposed to include the path to the math library ‘**libm.a**’ as follows:

```
$ gcc -Wall calc.c /usr/lib/libm.a -o calc
```

It would be very inconvenient to have to specify the paths to built in libraries that we use in our programs.  I can understand the reason for adding the path to my own custom libraries, but **libm.a** is built into gcc.  And although the book is quite old (published in 2004), *what has changed with more modern versions of gcc*, so that we do not need to include the path to **libm.a**?

*** UPDATE ***

I noticed that the answer given by taskinoor demonstrates updated code that requires that I use the **-lm** flag if the value passed to sqrt() is not known at compile time.

I learned C/C++ using VS but my goal now is to learn and use gcc.  I have Visual Studio 2013 and the VS compiler/linker does not seem so picky.  For example, I am able to compile just about any simple program without having to specify mysterious compiler flags.

I am learning on **gcc version 5.4** that comes with KUBUNTU 16.04.1

Comment: First, try a different book because for decades, the standard way to link a math library has been to use -lm instead of a full path to the library.  Second, https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html contains the release changes.

Comment: @JohnGriffin: From the same book: *"To avoid the need to specify long paths on the command line, the compiler provides a short-cut option ‘-l’ for linking against libraries. For example, the following command,
`$ gcc -Wall calc.c -lm -o calc` is equivalent to the original command..."*

Comment: Note that the default these days is to link with dynamic libraries, not static libraries. Maybe what you meant to ask about was linking with *standard* libraries?

Comment: Recent versions of gcc fix this bug (failing to link libm by default)

Comment: @M.M, I am using gcc 5.4 (Kubuntu 16.04.1) and I must use the -lm flag.  Which version of gcc are you using?  I am new to Linux and tried installing gcc 6 on Debian 8 Jessie and ended up with a broken GUI desktop.  I formatted and installed Kubuntu because of the newer gcc compiler, although I wish that I was using gcc 6 of course.

Comment: the `-lm`  is part of the options to the compiler.  a `-L`  (capital 'L') is used to tell the compiler where libraries are located. I.E. /usr/lib.   certain libraries, like `libc.so` are included automatically; the `libm.so` is not one of them.  To tell the linker to search that specific library the `-lm`  (lower case 'L') parameter is used (at the end of the link statement.) How did `libm.so` become `m`? because when referencing libraries, the leading `lib` and trailing `.so` are dropped.  Similar considerations apply for static libraries like: `libm.a`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sqrt (2.0);`

Modern GCC is well capable to determine that you are trying to find square root of a constant and thus it is able to calculate that in compile time. Your object code does not contain an actual call to `sqrt`.

If you use a variable which is input via `scanf` at run then it won't link without `libm`.

```
int main() {
    double x;

    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("%lf\n", sqrt(x));

    return 0;
}
```

Without `libm` gcc 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 this results:

```
/tmp/ccVO2fRY.o: In function `main':
sqrt.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But if I put a constant instead of `x` like your example then it links fine without `libm`.

P.S: I don't know the exact version since when GCC is able to do this. Hopefully someone else can point to that.

Comment: I get that error on Linux as well, but no error on OS X.

Comment: @Barmar no linker error on OS X with variables that can't be resolved at compile time? Sorry, I don't know about OS X. Probably something else is going on there.

Comment: @taskinoor, thank you for your helpful answer.  Without the -lm flag, I get almost the identical error you mention above.  I am using gcc 5.4 and will try to upgrade if a newer version of gcc fixes this.

Comment: @Barmar, I don't get the linker error with taskinoor's snippet on VC 2013 but I must use the -lm flag with gcc 5.4

Comment: So the overall explanation is that the default set of libraries is implementation-dependent. I don't think the C language spec covers linking with system libraries, it just specifies the header files that contain the declarations.

Comment: @Barmar my point was on some compiler (e.g. gcc on Linux) there is no need to link with libraries with constant values if that can be resolved at compiler time. But yes, looks like that is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that on some operating systems, common libraries are available without explicit linking. In particular, I've often taken a working C project originally developed on my Mac, and the project would not compile on Linux until I explicitly linked against the libraries I used (like libm).

Of course, this is typically for dynamic rather than static linking...